# python iterate row one by one mysql field

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying a program where I have 'table= qwes' and 'field1= first, field2= second".  I need to attain each row once, which must pass through the condition 'if a row has got hello, then its true else false'.

I used limit and needed to increment offset and then it has to loop back for next row finding true or false.  Likewise it should end till all the rows are finished.

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="mysql", # your password
                      db="sakila") # name of the data base

cursor = db.cursor()

qas = 0

while(qas < 100)
qas = qas + 1
posts = "select * from ques LIMIT 1 OFFSET %s " %(qas)

cursor.execute(posts)
db.commit()
keywords=[]
a='hello'
for i in cursor_posts.fetchall():
    keywords.append(i[0])
    if a in keywords:
      print true
    else:
      print false 
    raw_input("please press enter to continue")
```

Please help me in fixing my program; I want the while loop to execute until are the rows available.  Due to my lack of knowledge I made it for default as 100.

Comment: no need to increment the offset . i dint understand loop back to next row.? are you saying loop to next row. is it previous row or next row

Comment: its next row that it has to loop then to next loop and so on.

Comment: why not just `select * from ques limit 100` and then loop through it afterwards? wouldn't need an offset and it only queries the db once instead of a bunch of times (much faster/better performance)

Comment: can you post some sample output of what the text would look like?

Comment: could u please just arrange over my program and it would be appreciated.

Comment: it must just print 'true false true false' but i need to make it work the functions properly which will be helpful for lots of my miniprojects.

Comment: .... im not asking about what it prints out. i understand that. im asking about the post... what is `i[0]` or `keywords` .. like what would some of the sample text be?

Comment: okok like "1st row= john says hello=>true ,2nd row = maria say bye=>false".I hope this is wat ur asking.

Comment: @user3774272 i just updated my answer to output the result how you specified in your last comment.. see the updated answer for a more complete result :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my recommendation would be to do somehting like this:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="mysql", # your password
                      db="sakila") # name of the data base

cursor = db.cursor()
posts = "select * from ques LIMIT 100"
cursor.execute(posts)
db.commit()
a='hello'
counter = 0

for j in cursor.fetchall():
    counter += 1
    if a in j[0]:
      print ("Row " + str(counter) + "= " + j[0] + " => True")
    else:
      print ("Row " + str(counter) + "= " + j[0] + " => False") 
    raw_input("please press enter to continue")
```

basically query the database once with 100 records... then loop through the fetchall() of your executed statement and check if 'hello' is in j[0] which is where your post would be... assuming the first column in your database is the post... if its an id then move it to j[1]... just run a debug on it as it goes and look at what is in `j` when you go through the for loop.. should be a simple fix if this doesn't work

Comment: ok but it shows error as :   ' if a in j[0]:
TypeError: argument of type 'long' is not iterable'

Comment: @user3774272 maybe try ensuring counter is an int by doing this. `counter = int(counter)` right after you make counter = 0

Comment: thanks for the vote! remember if you want to do everything and not just 100 just remove the `LIMIT 100` clause and that should be it :) have fun!

Comment: a small doubt,how to print an record from table?